# Azure Media Services v3 - VideoOverlay

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I need help with Azure Media Services v3.

I read official [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-advanced-encoding-with-mes#overlay) but .NET SDK for .NET Core haven't **CloudMediaContext** and so on.

I need this feature:

**Options 1**

1. Create short video from original. This video is used for preview
2. Video in step 1 must have overlay (Only Video).

How Can I meet requirements?

For step 1 I think that I create filter? Or I need to create new assets with overlay and upload blob?

**Options 2**

1. Create thumbnails as describe [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-dotnet-core-tutorials/blob/master/NETCore/EncodeCustomTransform/MediaV3ConsoleApp/Program.cs#L233)
2. Image in step 1 must have overlay (Only Image)

How Can I meet requirements?

Answer (score 0):

At this time, the v3 APIs do not support overlays. This and other advanced features in the Standard Encoder have not yet been exposed via v3 APIs - see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/migrate-from-v2-to-v3#feature-gaps-with-respect-to-v2-apis) document for other such gaps. The product team is working on closing these gaps.